# How to get GridLookUpEdit's EditValue?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a GridLookUpEdit and wath to get a edit value on  FocusedRowChanged event:

```
    private void gridView_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var view = sender as GridView;
        if (view != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(view.GetRowCellValue(e.FocusedRowHandle, view.Columns[1]).ToString());
        }
    }
```

But here i get a error says that i out of column array. But i have a two columns, first column visible, second not visible.
Whats wrong here? And how can i get EditValue more correctly if possible?

Comment: Is this true: `view.Columns.Count == 2`?

Comment: @nempoBu4: `Count = 1`. But how it can be if i have a two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your view has only one column and there are two columns in your underlying datasource. So, you can get a value from underlying datasource.
If your underlying datasource is `DataTable` then you can use [`ColumnView.GetDataRow`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetDataRowtopic) method:

```
MessageBox.Show(view.GetDataRow(e.FocusedRowHandle)[1].ToString());
```

If your underlying datasource is `List<SomeObject>` then you can use [`ColumnView.GetDataSourceRowIndex`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetDataSourceRowIndextopic) method:

```
MessageBox.Show(YourList[view.GetDataSourceRowIndex()].YourColumn.ToString());
```

Or you can add second column by using `ColumnView.Columns` collection:

```
var column = view.Columns.AddField("YourField");
column.Visible = false;
```

Comment: I was besure that i have a two columns in GridView? becouse added it by myself. But right noew i check it and there is only one column. Maybe something go wrong in visual studio. Anyway thanks for answer)